# Why this.prototype is undefined in Constructor?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

tl;dr: it's possible to access an object `prototype` in its *Constructor* with `Object.getPrototypeOf(this)`. It is not with simply: `this.prototype`. Why?

I have a simple question. I think Ecmascript-5 experts will help me shed some light on the mysterious `this`.

My aim is to write some reference code to declare a class through a *constructor* embedded in an *IIFE* (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) and apply this didactic pattern as a template when needed. What's nice with this construct is it allows declaring instance and class data. It's also nice too to have all methods in the `prototype` *Object*. [Here is what I came up with](https://codepen.io/Djee/pen/vaLQpW):

```
var Person = (function(){
  // class scope variables
  var persons = [];
  // constructor with variables
  return function(name, age){
   // gets the prototype of Object: useful for defining methods
   // could also be: proto = Person.prototype
   var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);
   // instance variable
   this.name = name;
   this.age = age;
   persons.push(this);
   // method which accesses to both class and instance variables
   if (!proto.stats) // avoids re-inventing the wheel upon each New
    proto.stats = function() {
     for(var acc=0, n=0; n<persons.length; n++)
      acc+=persons[n].age;
     return this.name + ": " + 
            this.age + " (average: " + acc/n + ")";
    };
   return this; // not required, just to remember what it does normally
  };
})(); // IIFE
// a classic method (cannot access class variables)
Person.prototype.toString = function(){
  return this.name + ": " + this.age + " years old";
};
```

I achieved my aim and this pattern looks fairly extensible, methods sit in the `prototype` *Object* not the instance. Something remains strange to me however: instead of the `var proto =` declaration and use of `proto` in the *Constructor* I first wanted to simply use `this.prototype`. But it is `undefined`. How come?

Side note: I found some hints in similar questions but to my understanding nothing close to mine.

Thank you for your time, knowledge, and attention.

Answer (score 4):

Try to follow the example below. I also recommend you read this book http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do to understand what you are doing in JavaScript.

```
function Car() {
  console.log(this)                 // I'm the new Car "instance"
  console.log(typeof this)          // I'm of type object
  console.log(this instanceof Car)  // but I'm an instance of Car
  console.log(this.prototype)       // I'm undefined because __proto__ is the reference to the prototype
  console.log(this.__proto__)       // This is the prototype
}

Car.prototype.drive = function drive() {
  console.log('I\'m driving')
}

const fiat = new Car()
fiat.drive()
```

Cheers,

Ash

Comment: Thank you. I have been advised to avoid using __proto__ as much as possible. So using getPrototypeOf instead seems a good choice.

Comment: Now I remember having learned this: basically, class, (i.e. Contructor) bears the prototype property not the instance! Sorry for the mistake.